# University life is one of the best parts in {anybody's/everybody's} life

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

> University life is one of the best parts in anybody's life.

Should I use **anybody's** life or **everybody's** life? and should I use **part** or **parts** of life. I am confused. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: one of the best times in x's life.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest "..best parts in anyone's life"

If you use everybody - does every person go to university?

I'd also point out, perhaps pedantically, that not everyone goes to university. And some people that do, have a terrible time.

Comment: Are you sure about using **in** instead of **of**. Best parts of life, best things in life, is how I would say it. I don't think it's good form to argue about what a learner would like to express in English, especially when you have such little context.